# Unitary matrix and it's adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

let's say we have unitary matrix A ,does adjoint(A) unitary too ?
I am not sure about that but i cant find counter example.
So i tried to start with the equation A * adj(A) = |A| * I
than because A unitary A^-1 exists so |A| != 0.
=> A * adj(A) / |A| = I  => A^-1 = A* = adj(A) / |A|
=> A* / |A| = adj(A) => [adj(A)]* = A / |A| (complementary) 
=> adj(A) * [adj(A)]* = (A* / |A| ) * (A / |A| (complementary)) = I / |A| ^ 2
but I am not sure about this prove.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have prove this:
$$A^{-1} = A^* =\frac{adj(A)}{|A|}$$
Remmember that $A^*$ is unitary, so from $adj(A)=|A|.A^*$ and $(adj(A))^*=|A|^*.A$ then $adj(A).(adj(A))^*=|A|.|A|^*.I=|A|.|A^*|.I=I$

Comment: oh! thank you i got it.